# Is it possible to add an already created form to a tab control?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tabpage

With this setup:

```
 Form1 
      tabControl1
           tab1
           tab2
 Form2
      button1
      textbox1
```

Is it possible to add Form2 to tab 2? So if I were to click on tab2, Form2 would show up within that tab?

Comment: why would you want to do that?  the tab is already a container control so you are just adding overhead (but yes it is possible)

Comment: @Plutonix There is no real reason for it, I am just overly curious if it can be done.

Comment: @ Ganesh_Devlekar I don't believe I have access to Iframe on a c# windows form.

Comment: It's possible by setting the `TopLevel` property of your Form2 instance to false at **run-time**, and then adding it to the TabPage controls collection before calling Show().  Note,  however, that controls displayed in forms this way do not behave correctly with respect to tabbing.  Use a **UserControl** instead of a form.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Nailed it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"@Idle_Mind Nailed it, thank you. –  Blankdud"

It's possible by setting the TopLevel property of your Form2 instance to false at run-time, and then adding it to the TabPage controls collection before calling Show(). Note, however, that controls displayed in forms this way do not behave correctly with respect to tabbing. Use a UserControl instead of a form.